# Cycling through URLs for Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

Hey this is my first post on here. Was trying to find similar answers to my question but I couldn't seem to find any.

Essentially what im trying to do is build a website item stock checker in python utilizing selenium. Ive got it all working but now im trying to scale it so that way I can check multiple links without having to open another instance of the application.

Ive been trying to make some sort of toggle where the script will default to 0 then as it finishes the first run through itll set it to 1 then reloop. Obviously I would have 0 = item url 1 and 1 = item url 2. Ive tried itertools cycle but that just doesn't seem to work.

If anyone has some advice id really appreciate it!

Comment: Why don't you store the links in a list and loop through the links to find what you are looking for while using `driver.get()`

Comment: Im not entirely sure how to do that. I tried sending two links through the driver.get() function but it only ever returns the first in the list.

Comment: you wouldn't send 2 links to diver.get() instead you would only send one link do your processing with a loop (which will allow you to do the same thing with your next link). Would you kindly post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I used your advice and figured it out. I appreciate it boss